# read multiple inputs with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm playing around with the todos.js backbone.js demo.

In the demo, they have one input text box where they take data from in the initialize function like this:

```
<input id="new-todo" type="text" placeholder="Todo item...">

initialize: function () {

        this.input = this.$("#new-todo");
```

My question is, would it be possible to take the data from 3 input textboxes instead of just one?

I could try this, but this doesn't seem to scale very well:

```
<input id="new-todo1" type="text" placeholder="Todo item...">
<input id="new-todo2" type="text" placeholder="Todo item...">
<input id="new-todo3" type="text" placeholder="Todo item...">
```

initialize: function () {

```
    this.input = this.$("#new-todo1");
    this.input =+ this.$("#new-todo2");
    this.input =+ this.$("#new-todo3");
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: that's not "taking the data", it's simpy caching the jQuery object inside a property of the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to take the values from multiple inputs, and put them as title in a todo item. I suggest storing references to inputs in **initialize** with:

```
initialize: function () {
   this.input = this.$("#new-todo");
   ...
}
```

And the **createOnEntermethod** should change into this:

```
createOnEnter: function(e) {

   //concatenate the values from all inputs
   var val = "";
   this.input.each(function() {
     val += ($(this).val());
   });

  if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
  if (!val) return;

  Todos.create({title: val});

  //reset all the input elements
  this.input.each(function() {
     $(this).val('');
  });
}
```

The input elements should all have the same id - "new-todo".

Answer (score 1):

I am not very experienced with Backbone.js but you could use jQuery each to loop through all of the inputs and get their value.

Answer (score 1):

if you have:

```
<input class="todo" type="text" placeholder="Todo item...">
<input class="todo" type="text" placeholder="Todo item...">
<input class="todo" type="text" placeholder="Todo item...">
```

then

```
initialize: function () {

    this.$inputs = this.$(".todos");
```

will cache those inputs (not get the value as you said).
then

```
this.$inputs.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

will print their values, or you could put their values in an array like so:

```
var values = this.$inputs.map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
});
```

then you can make a string out of those values with

```
values.join(' ');
```

or you can use `Underscore`'s `reduce` for extra style points:

```
var string = _(this.$inputs).reduce(function(memo, el) {
  return memo + ' ' + $(el).html();
}, '');
```